# android play video of all extensions

Tags: android, video

after a long try and searching on the net i found no way to play video with all extensions programmatically. I tried videoView and other android normal tools that play just few video extension and tried to configure android vlc player but it failed to run.

can any body help me to play videos with all extensions or convert them to standard extension that android can play them such as MP4 (conversion can be server side and no programming language restriction exists)

Comment: No platform can play the video of every extension. You need the appropriate codecs and the supported codec list is given here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: I am managing to develop a video sharing app on android, at list it must provide a wide veracity of videos something more than normal android codec witch MX player and VLC player do

Answer (score 0):

I installed the following programs on my android device and so far it plays all video formats...

- MX player pro
- FLV video player
- MOBO video player pro

Comment: I want to play video programatically in my code does they support play by intent ? (MX player is not even free)